# How to get status code response from a Github repo using Octokit?

Tags: ruby, octokit

I'm currently trying to retrieve the status code returned by a Github repo. I have tried to use the `#response_status` [doc](https://octokit.github.io/octokit.rb/Octokit/Error.html), but the documentation isn't very clear on how to create an instance of Octokit:: Error class. And, I can't seem to invoke the method to retrieve the status code.

```rb
      #create an instance of the class  
      @git_client_error = Octokit::Error.new
      ....
      # sample usage
      @git_client_error.response_status
```

Any examples of implementation using the response_status in ruby would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please explain how you're using the API and what you're actually trying to do?  You should not need to instantiate an error object to use the api. The ruby client should handle that for you. See documenation at https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb

Comment: @lacostenycoder I was trying to get a status code response back from the repo, to see whether the octokit api managed to establish a connection and doesn't get a 403 error.  After a successful connection has been made, I will list all the issues listed in that repo.

Comment: Aren't you instantiating a client?  Your example doesn't show anything about where in your workflow you are.  If you have a client, you should be able to authenticate by login username / password or an access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume you followed the instructions in the [github repo readme](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb), you should have a client object. From there, you make requests on the client. To check the status code you can check responses.  Each client request makes an http request.

```
client = Octokit::Client.new(:login => 'somebody', :password => 'something!')
# now make any request
user = client.user
# client.user should return a user object instance of Sawyer::Resource class
response = client.last_response
response.status
=> 200
```